# cannot find symbol MainReactPackage

Tags: android, react-native

I have ejected my react native app to Expokit. I am trying to use [react native firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase). After following the setup instructions for react native firebase as given on [android installation page](https://invertase.io/react-native-firebase/#/installation-android), when I execute 'react-native run-android' I get an error:

```
MainApplication.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
new MainReactPackage(),
    ^
symbol: class MainReactPackage
location: class MainApplication
```

The MainApplication.java looks like this:

```
package com.abc.xyz;

import android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import io.invertase.firebase.RNFirebasePackage; 
import io.invertase.firebase.analytics.RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage; // Firebase Analytics
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;

public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

  public List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new RNFirebasePackage(),  
          new RNFirebaseAnalyticsPackage()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: show the full MainApplication.java

Comment: @YaShChaudhary I added the code

Answer (score 15):

Try adding this line to your `MainApplication.java`:

`import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;`

Comment: Tried that already (also did ./gradlew clean). It throws another error on output:

:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzaj.class

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Comment: ok!. means you tried `cd android` and `./gradlew clean` . ok try deleting `app-debug.apk` from `android/app/build/outputs/apk`

Comment: Yes. I had run ./gradlew clean inside android directory. There is no apk folder in my android/app/build/outputs/